# Does Android guarantee order of intents?

Tags: android, concurrency, android-intent

When sending two intents (One through `startService` followed by another through `startActivityForResult` for the sake of an example), does Android guarantee that the first intent (service) is processed before the second (activity)? More specifically in this case, does it guarantee that the `Service.onStartCommand` is called before the `Activity.onCreate`?

This is assuming that everything runs within the same process so threading issues from several main threads don't interfere.

I know that Android doesn't guarantee the processing order for a single intent (The order of recipients isn't guaranteed but can be affected by the intent filter priority) but I couldn't find anything mentioning the order between intents.

Personally I would have thought that, given the single main application thread, the order would be maintained, but I'm facing some bugs that I have hard time explaining unless the order of intents changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help. 
[BroadcastReceiver Developer Page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

The key bit being that an intent which starts an activity is very different semantically.

It seems like it'd be quite easy to test order by logging.

Comment: Had completely missed that part. I guess these things go complicated deep in Android internals since they need to span VM borders - the issue with testing is that most of the time it seems to work as expected. I'll just assume it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

1. I do not believe that Android makes any kind of guarantee - <strike>in particular, I believe that `Context.startService` would be asynchronous</strike>. **Edit**: After your comment, I believe that you are right in that `startService` will only return after the service has called its `onCreate` method. However, if the `Service` is in another application, then it will usually not run in the same process, let alone in the same thread.
2. Android probably does not make this guarantee because it has already stated that while it will *try* to keep services running, it could *theoretically* kill the service between your call to `Context.startService` and your call to `Activity.startActivityForResult`.
3. Why would you need such a guarantee in the first place? Get the service by `startService` or `bindService` when you need it, specify what should happen to your application when it hits its lifecycle phases, and let Android manage the lifecycle itself.

Footnote: Also, if your `Activity` is already running, the `onCreate` method may not be called when you call `onActivityStart`.

Comment: I don't know how startService would be asynchronous as Android services don't imply multi-threading, they share the main application loop. The full story in this case is a server browser launching the background connection and a client activity. The client activity finishes when the service goes into 'disconnected' state (in which it is created by default if it didn't exist in the first place). I guess I need to wait in the browser until connected and only then move into the client activity even if that requires the browser to track service state as well, which complicates things.

Comment: You're right - `startService` is probably not asynchronous - returning only after `onStart` has returned.